# How to fix selector on this combination bath tap/shower setup?

Tags: faucet, bathtub, plumbing-fixture

I have a combination tap/shower setup for my bath that looks like this:

[image: Combination tap/shower]

The lever in the middle can be rotated left or right to choose between whether the water comes out the tap or out of the showerhead. Recently it has come loose and will just rotate left/right without doing anything. With a bit of jiggling you can get the mechanism to engage and it will function. I'm assuming that there is a loose screw or similar that could be tightened to fix the lever back in place but I can't figure out how I would be able to access such a screw.

While I doubt anyone will be familiar with this exact model, I assume there a few a standard ways for this to work. Where should I start trying to dismantle it? I am in Germany in case that is relevant to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The porcelain handle might unscrew showing more options to get inside the diverter valve.

  - It might just need to come off to be out of the way.
  - It might *not* unscrew and may come off as you complete the following steps.
- At the pivot point of that handle, there appears to be a porcelain covered button with gold trim.

  - COVER YOUR DRAIN SO YOU DON'T LOOSE PARTS
  - Gently prying behind that gold trim should pop this button off revealing a screw behind it. A strong fingernail is probably sufficient to pop the button off, if not, use a plastic screwdriver, old credit card or similar to avoid scratching the finish. If you don't have something plastic, carefully use a small flat blade screwdriver to pry.
  - Unscrewing that will allow further disassembly.
  - Take a lot of pics (better: have someone take them for you) as you disassemble so you can remember how to reassemble it.

Once you've got it disassembled, if you're not sure what's failing or how to fix it, please feel free to ask a new question about that portion of the process.

Comment: The handle does indeed unscrew although it revealed nothing useful. However after a little wiggling the whole thing fell off and looking inside revealed a brass screw at the end under the gold/porcelain cap which appeared to hold the assembly in place but was currently inaccessible.

Comment: The cap was firmly stuck in place though so I spent some time trying to pry it off and applied a little WD40 whereupon it loosened up enough for me to realise that it was actually screwed in place rather than being a press fit. Once that was done it was easy enough to refit and tighten the screw and it's all working well again. However I assume it will loosen itself over time since presumably the repeated left/right rotations worked the screw loose. Anything I can do to secure the screw more firmly?

Comment: Glad you got it figured out @JackAidley! Your follow up question is an excellent opportunity to hit the ["Ask Question" button](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Down here, nobody will find your question or the answer. It deserves to get attention of its own.

Comment: I didn't think it was worth a question of its own, but perhaps it is.

Comment: You can also search the site (or the internet in general) for questions on how to keep a screw from coming loose.